# ARM parity of low 8 bits of a register

Tags: assembly, arm, thumb, parity

I have found a few difficulties with the assembly language and unfortunately when I search the google for information I can't find anything that helps me with my problem.
I have written this code and I'm looking for help to see if there's a way to make it more simple (if possible). Also if the comments are wrong please let me know.

```
        NAME main
        PUBLIC main
        SECTION .text: CODE (2)
        THUMB

main    
        LDR R4, =0x0097         ; R4 = 97 in hex 
        BL SUBROUTINE           ; Go to Subroutine

STOP    B STOP

SUBROUTINE
        MOV R1, #1              ; Initialize R1 to 1        
        MOV R2, #0              ; Initialize R2 to 0        
        MOV R0, #0              ; Initialize R0 to 0        
        PUSH {R4}               

LOOP
        CMP R0, #8              ; Bits counter
        BEQ DONE                ; Go to DONE R0 = 8
        ADD R0, R0, #1          ; Calculates the bits
        AND R3, R4, R1          ; Checks if R3 = R4
        CMP R3, #1              ; Comparing result with 1
        BEQ ONE                 ; Jump to ONE
        LSR R4, R4, #1          ; Right shift by 1
        B LOOP

ONE
        ADD R6, R6, #1          ; Saving #1 in R6
        LSR R4, R4, #1          ; Right shift by 1
        B LOOP

RETURN0
        MOV R2, #0              
        POP {R4}
        B STOP

RETURN1
        MOV R2, #1
        POP {R4}
        B STOP

DONE
        CMP R6, #2
        BEQ RETURN0
        CMP R6, #4
        BEQ RETURN0
        CMP R6, #6
        BEQ RETURN0
        CMP R8, #8
        BEQ RETURN0
        B RETURN1

        END
```

The task is the following:
The subroutine has an input parameter in register R4 and delivers a return
value in the register R2. The subroutine will check the parity of the 8 least
significant bits of the input parameter. If the parity is even, the value 0 is
returned, if the parity is odd then the value 1 is returned. Even parity means
that the number of ones is even, and the odd parity of the number of ones
is odd.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Anything that makes it harder to help you will result in much less chance of you getting help. Specifically, you should include your code ***in the question as text,*** not on an external site as an image.

Comment: Your post might be more appropriate for [codereview.SE], given that there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code.

Answer (score 5):

Your programming style is already pretty good and you thoroughly comment your code.  This is very valuable and something you should keep doing.  The algorithm itself seems correct and is implemented in an acceptable manner, though it could be done more efficiently.

*I've been writing this answer under the assumption that you are programming in ARM mode.  However, much of the advice applies to Thumb mode as well.  I suppose you cannot use Thumb 2 instructions.  Advice specific to thumb is noted in slanted font.*

The most important thing when writing efficient assembly code is to know the instruction set of the architecture you are programming for.  Your code is written for ARM which has many useful instructions and features to speed things up.  Let's start with some basic improvements.

First of all, you use this sequence to isolate the least significant bit of `R4` to then check if it is nonzero:

```
        ADD R0, R0, #1          ; Calculates the bits
        AND R3, R4, R1          ; Checks if R3 = R4
        CMP R3, #1              ; Comparing result with 1
        BEQ ONE                 ; Jump to ONE
```

This can be done more efficiently.  First, note that you can use immediates with the `AND` instruction, so there's no need to keep a 1 in a register just for this:

```
        AND   R3, R4, #1
```

next, instead of comparing the result of the bitwise `AND` with `#1`, you can tell the processor to set the flags directly from the result of the `AND` instruction.  This sets the zero flag if the result is zero (and possible some other flags, don't care too much about that), so you can immediately branch on the result.

```
        ANDS  R3, R4, #1        ; check if least significant bit set in R4
        BNE   ONE               ; jump to ONE if it is
```

Now this `ANDS` does the jobs but needlessly writes its result to `R3`.  We don't really need it there.  A quick look at the instruction set reference tells us that `TST` does the same thing as `ANDS` but discards the result, setting just the flags.  This is exactly what we want.

```
        TST   R4, #1            ; check if least signficant bit set in R4
        BNE   ONE               ; jump to ONE if it is
```

Now the next thing we can do is get rid of that conditional branch.  The only difference between the code in the `ONE` branch is that it increments `R6`.  Instead of a conditional branch, we can simply use ARM's *conditional execution* feature to execute an `ADD` instruction only when the zero flag is set:

```
        TST   R4, #1             ; check if least significant bit set in R4
        ADDNE R6, R6, #1         ; increment R6 if it is
```

This makes the code quite a bit more efficient!  We can improve even further by merging the `TST` into the `LSR` instruction.  See, if we tell `LSR` to set flags, it sets the carry flag to the last bit that was shifted out.  That's exactly what we are interested in!  So we can just do

```
        LSRS  R4, R4, #1         ; shift R4 to the right and set flags
        ADDCS R6, R6, #1         ; increment R6 if a 1 was shifted out
```

Note that on other architectures where conditional execution is not available, you can reach a similar effect to `ADDCS R6, R6, #1` using an add-with-carry instruction:

```
        ADC   R6, R6, #0         ; add 1 to R6 if carry is set
```

*This is what I would do in thumb mode, too.  As there's no immediate-operand `ADC` in thumb mode, you have to keep one register set to zero.*

```
        MOVS  R1, #0
        ...
        LSRS  R4, R4, #1
        ADCS  R6, R1, #0         ; add carry to R6
```

Apart from setting the carry flag, `LSRS` also sets the zero flag if the result is zero.  Thus, we can do away with the loop counter if we simply iterate until all bits in `R4` have been shifted out, saving us a register and a bunch of instruction.  Note that this may not yield correct results if any extra bits (apart from the least 8 bit you check) are set in `R4`, so you might want to mask these out with `AND R4, R4, #0xff` first.  And here's the code:

```
LOOP:   LSRS  R4, R4, #1         ; shift R4 to the right and set flags
        ADDCS R6, R6, #1         ; increment R6 if a 1 was shifted out
        BNE   LOOP               ; loop until R4 is 0.
```

*Unfortunately, all thumb instructions set flags, so you can't do this optimisation.*

You can similarly optimise the code in the `DONE` part: essentially, you just check if `R6` is even or odd and return `1` if it is odd or `0` if it is even.  You can replace the whole cascade of jumps with a single test:

```
        TST   R6, #1             ; set the zero flag if R6 is even
        BEQ   RETURN0            ; return 0 if even
        B     RETURN1            ; otherwise return 1
```

But then, realise that this is basically the same as returning the least significant bit of `R6`, so you can replace this whole code by

```
        AND   R0, R6, #1         ; set R0 to 1 if R6 is odd, 0 if R6 is even
        POP   {R4}
        B     STOP
```

This is quite a bit shorter, isn't it?

*In thumb code, similar performance can be achieved using some clever thinking.  Note that we only care about the least significant bit of `R6` and trashing the high bits doesn't matter.  Thus we can write*

```
        MOVS R0, #0              ; parity accumulator
        SUBS R1, R0, #2          ; mask (clear in bit 0, 1 everywhere else)
LOOP:   LSRS R4, R4, #1          ; shift out one bit from R4 and set flags
        ADCS R0, R0, R1          ; add that bit to R0
        CMP  R4, #0              ; are we done?
        BNE  LOOP                ; loop until we are
        BICS R0, R1              ; isolate parity
```

*The result can then be found in `R0`.*

Now for some algorithmic improvements: your code does the trick, but it is indeed quite slow as it does one iteration per digit.  A faster approach is to zip bits together using `XOR` instructions.  This allows us to compute the parity in just 3 steps instead of 8 as your code does:

```
        LSR   R3, R6, #4        ; keep a copy of R6 shifted by 4 places
        EOR   R6, R6, R3        ; and xor it into R6
        LSR   R3, R6, #2
        EOR   R6, R6, R3        ; same but shifted by 2 places
        LSR   R3, R6, #1
        EOR   R6, R6, R3        ; same but shifted by 1 place
        AND   R0, R6, #1        ; isolate parity
```

*The same code can be written in thumb mode, but you might need some additional data moves in between.*

This can be improved further using shifted operands, another ARM-specific feature:

```
        EOR   R6, R6, R6, LSR #4 ; xor R6 with R6 shifted right 4 places
        EOR   R6, R6, R6, LSR #2 ; xor R6 with R6 shifted right 2 places
        EOR   R6, R6, R6, LSR #1 ; xor R6 with R6 shifted right 1 place
        AND   R0, R6, #1         ; isolate parity
```

This is the generally fastest approach without using any instruction set extensions.  If you have a sufficiently advanced processor, you can use the `CNT` instruction to count bits in one step, but that's not really worth the effort here anyway.

Comment: @TomášChabada: this pattern of bringing the high half down and combining, works for any associative reduction, successively narrowing down to 1 element in log2(width) steps.  e.g. SIMD horizontal sum / product / min / max / AND / OR / XOR of vector elements.  In this case, XOR of bits in a single register, since bitwise operations don't have any carry-out that disturbs adjacent bits.  But yes, it's a good trick to know, and even cooler on ARM which can shift as part of another instruction.

Comment: this is thumb not arm, would we call that a predicated and? (from other question today).  Likewise with the eors, have to look those up though...awesome answer for arm though.  might just leave that as if arm then else if thumb then and show what can be done there, two answers in one...

Comment: ahh the homework defines r4 if the requirement was copied correctly thus the r4/r5 perhaps in the other question...

Comment: @old_timer oh... I totally missed that this is a thumb question.  Will have to rework the answer to address this.

Comment: I would seriously do the if this was arm this is what you can do being thumb this is what you are limited to...and not lose the great work here.

Answer (score 0):

next time use CODE (curly brackets in editor) instead of printscreen (you cannot copy-paste from prtscn for example).
I have never used ARM assembly language, but I'd use this approach:

1. AND-out top 24 bits (if you are not sure that they'll be always 0s) of your input
2. Move input to any GPR (let's say R5)
3. Move R5 into any other GPR (let's say R6)
4. AND-out all bits of R6 except least significant one
5. Test R6 for zero (if not zero, increment some counter (GPR))
6. Logical shift R5 right
7. Go to 3. (repeat eight times)
8. You have number of 1s in your counter

This would be my approach. I am not sure if it's the best, though. It should be simplier. If ARM has any way to rotate through carry, it would be even easier (you'd skip incrementing of counter if carry bit is zero).

Comment: Rotate through carry is available through the `RRX` instruction / shift modifier.

Comment: Good to know (as I have already said, I have no experience with ARM). Then it would be quite easy to just logical shift right - jump if not carry over counter incrementation. I also fully agree with you that ASM programming requires quite a deep knowledge of architecture.

Comment: I've addressed a bunch of approaches in this direction in my question.  I don't think you need `RRX` as the speciality of a rotate-through-carry is to be able to rotate the carry flag in which isn't something you need here.  Rotating/shifting out into the carry flag is something all shifts and rotates do on ARM (if you ask for flags to be set), so that can be achieved easily.  ARM is a lot of fun with all the flexibility the instruction set gives you.

Comment: If you wanted to implement parity as `popcount(x) & 1` using a simplistic count loop one bit at a time, you could right-shift to move a bit from the register into the carry flag, then `adc r6, 0` to add CF into another register.  Fun fact: x86 has a parity flag that's updated according to the low 8 bits of every result, so `test al, al` / `setp al` could give you the parity in 2 instructions on x86.  But ARM doesn't have that.